# In Ruby on Rails, if a note has many tags, how do I check if a note has any tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried note.tags.nil?, but it didn't work. How do I do this? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if a `@note` has any associated `tags`, you can use

```
@note.tags.empty?
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition, you could think about having a counter cache column for Tags. With that `:tags_count` you wouldn't need another SQL query. You could check then with `@note.tags_count == 0`, `@note.tags_count.zero?` or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `@note.tags.any?` to test if there are any tags. Note that this will hit the database to do a count. You might want to left join when pulling out `@note`, to save this query. Eg.:

```
Note.first(:select => 'notes.*, case when tags.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as has_any_tags', :joins => "LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.note_id = notes.id")
```

Your `Note` model will now have a field `has_any_tags` that is either `0` (false) or `1` (true), if there are any related tags.

You can move the query options above into a default scope and wrap the field up in an accessor:

```
class Note
  has_many :tags
  default_scope :select => 'notes.*, case when tags.id is not null then 1 else 0 end as has_any_tags', :joins => "LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.note_id = notes.id"
  def has_any_tags?
    has_any_tags == "1"
  end
end
```

Now, it all happens transparently:

```
>> Note.first.has_any_tags?
=> true
```